# Join Array of Objects by Property using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way using lodash or another library to join an array of objects?

I'm looking for a readymade function not a for loop.

For example:

```
[{a: 1}, {a:3}, {a: 4}]
      //Run a function by specifing the property a and setting "," as the delimeter
Get 1,3,4
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is your lodash answer

```
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a:3}, {a: 4}];
var s = _.map(arr, 'a').join(',');
//s == '1,2,3,4'
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need lodash for this, you can just use `map` and `join`:

```js
let collection = [{a: 1}, {a:3}, {a: 4}];
alert(collection.map(item => item.a).join(','));
```

Comment: hehe ecma script... lucky man since you are allowed to use it =)

Comment: @java_newbie you are absolutely right, maybe you can get your team to use a transpiler and some polyfills - worth the headache!